# Tune parameters with nested SVM in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I have a dataset of 20 test subjects with 50 variables and a result vector of `1` and `0` that determines their state. I would like to set up a nested cross validation such that I in the inner folds perform feature selection as well as tuning the hyperparameters of the SVM. Then these parameters should be tested on the outer fold.

I have previously done this in regards to feature selection with a logistic regression (using sequentialfs), but I am at a loss as how to do both the feature selection and the tuning of hyperparameters at the same time.

Some sample code would be ideal, but a general explanation of the setup and interpretation of a given output would also be helpful, as I am new to SVM.

The feature selection must be forwards. If possible, I would like the output to be the best overall SVM with parameters and chosen features. Naturally I would also like to know the errorrate on the test sets. The kernel used is the polynomial of second order, so I suppose there is only one parameter to tune?

Furthermore I would like it to be 5-fold on both inner and outer cross validation.

**EDIT: I have found some sample code, that should do what I want, but I can't seem to make it work. Can anyone explain how to set it up in MATLAB?**

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/nested-cross-validation-for-classification-in-matlab

Comment: How do you want to do the feature selection? Forward or Backward? Also, what do you want as output? Do want the _best_ overall SVM with its parameters and its chosen features? Or do you want to simply know the accuracy/performance of the SVM in the average case? Please give more details w.r.t. the output.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Pablo. I have added some answers to the questions you had - hope this clarifies.

Comment: have a look at my proposed answer. I am not doing the 5-fold CV on the inner-most loop for parameter selection because I just saw your new edit. Let me know if the answer is acceptable _as is_, or if you still need the 5-folds in the _inner most_ loop. It should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following answer, where `allData` contains all the data. Every row is an entry and every column is a feature. A variable called `targets` will contain the objective classes.  With this assumptions I am going to explain the code attached below, part by part.

A variable `featSize` will have the number of features.

```
featSize = size(allData, 2);
```

A variable `kFolds` will contain the number of folds you want. You said `5` but I suggest you at least `10`, if you have sufficiency of data.

```
kFolds = 5;
```

A structure `bestSVM` will be the "output" you need. You can clear all variables at the end, except for this one. The structure will contain the best SVM and its parameter and the index of the features that will yield the best performance.

```
bestSVM = struct('SVMModel', NaN, 'C', NaN, 'FeaturesIdx', NaN, 'Score', Inf);
```

A variable `kIdx` will contain the cross validation indices based on the data and the number of folds. It uses matlab's function [crossvalind()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html).

```
kIdx = crossvalind('Kfold', length(targets), kFolds);
```

Now, the main *outer* loop will run for as many folds you specified in `kFolds` and will prepare a training set and a testing set (`trainData`, `testData`) with its corresponding targets (`trainTarg`, `testTarg`) as follows:

```
for k = 1:kFolds
    trainData = allData(kIdx~=k, :);
    trainTarg = targets(kIdx~=k);
    testData = allData(kIdx==k, :);
    testTarg = targets(kIdx==k);
```

Now, we prepare for feature selection. We initialize a variable `bestFeatScore` to `Inf` so that later we can compare the performance of an SVM (score) to that value (it may make more sense further down). We also initialize a structure `bestFeatCombo` that will contain the best `SVM` among all possible feature combinations with its corresponding feature indices `feat`, and parameter `C`.

```
    bestFeatScore = inf;
    bestFeatCombo = struct('SVM', NaN, 'feat', NaN, 'C', NaN);
```

The possible number of feature combinations is `2^featSize - 1`. E.g., if you have two features in total, you have `2^2 - 1 = 3` choices: 1) choose feature 1 only, 2) choose feature 2 only, 3) choose feature 1 and 2 only. Thus, we need a `for` loop to go over all possible combinations of features.

```
    for b = 1:(2^featSize) - 1
```

However, there is a tricky part (for which I am sure there is a better solution out-there) where you want to start choosing sets of features first. I thought of this as a binary representation problem. Say that you have three features in total `[f1, f2, f3]`, then, we could say that the binary vector `[1, 0, 0]` represents the selection of feature `f1` and neglects the rest. Passing a binary vector to matlab will give you an error of indexing. So, the best way I found to solve this is to use matlab's [find()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function that will find the "indices and values of nonzero elements". Thus, if we do `featCombo = find([1, 0, 0])`, the variable `featCombo` would be equal to `1`. So, what I did was use the variable `b` (from the for loop above) that will contain a number indicating the current possible combination of features and convert it to a binary vector of size `featSize` using matlab's function [de2bi()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html). For instance, `de2bi(1, 3)` gives `[1, 0, 0]` which, as you noticed uses the left digit as the least significant. `de2bi(3, 3)` gives `[1, 1, 0]`, `de2bi(5, 3)` gives `[1, 0, 1]`, and so on. Then, if you use the `find()` function over a `de2bi()` will result on the indexes of the features you want to choose from.

```
        featCombo = find(de2bi(b, featSize));
```

For example, if `featSize = 3`, this:

```
for b = 1:(2^featSize) - 1; display(de2bi(b, featSize)); end;
```

would give you *something like* this:

```
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 1     1     0
 0     0     1
 1     0     1
 0     1     1
 1     1     1
```

which combined with find as follows:

```
for b = 1:(2^featSize) - 1; display(find(de2bi(b, featSize))); end;
```

would give you *something like* this:

```
 1
 2
 1     2
 3
 1     3
 2     3
 1     2     3
```

which is suitable for use as [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/). So, `featCombo` will contain the set (vector with the indices) of features to be chosen.

The next part will initialize variables for [grid search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization) for the BoxConstraint `C` which is also known as a hyper-parameter (depending on the SVM type you may have other parameters).  `bestCScore` will contain the best performance of an SVM during grid search, `bestC` will contain the best `C` parameter, and `bestCSVM` will have the best trained SVM during the search. The variable `gridC` will contain the search space, which in my example goes from `2^-5`, `2^-3`, to `2^15`. If you have plenty of computational resources, I suggest you to change `2.^(-5:2:15)` to a smaller increment, like `2.^(-5:1:15)`, or even smaller, `2.^(-5:0.1:15)` but be careful as it will take a while to finish. Similarly, if you have low computational power (or limited time) increase the interval to `2.^(-5:3:15)` or even `2.^(-5:4:15)`, knowing that it will poorly chose the hyper-parameter.

```
        bestCScore = inf;
        bestC = NaN;
        bestCSVM = NaN;
        gridC = 2.^(-5:2:15);
```

Next, we will start the grid search based on the array `gridC` and we will train an SVM using matlab's function [fitcsvm()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html). The SVM is trained with the current `trainData` determined by the *current fold*, and with the specific chosen features as determined by `featCombo`. The training targets `trainTarg` are determined by the current fold as well. Note that a) I am using an RBF kernel type (since you did not specify it), and b) I am letting matlab *auto determine* the kernel scale. If you want to use another kernel, this code will need some modification.

```
        for C = gridC
            anSVMModel = fitcsvm(trainData(:, featCombo), trainTarg, ...
                'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
                'BoxConstraint', C);
```

The next step is to determine how well the SVM performed for that parameter, for that set of features, for that fold. We do this with the function [loss()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationsvm.loss.html) for SVMs.

```
            L = loss(anSVMModel,testData(:, featCombo), testTarg);
```

If the current SVM (`anSVMModel`) performed better than the previous best performance we will save the score into `bestCScore`, the best parameter into `bestC`, and the best SVM into `bestCSVM`.

```
            if L < bestCScore
                bestCScore = L;
                bestC = C;
                bestCSVM = anSVMModel;
            end
        end
```

At the end of the *inner-most* loop, we should have the best hyper-parameter and SVM for the current feature set. So, if it this SVM has a better score than any other previously trained SVM for any other feature set, we will save that SVM, that set of features, and that hyper-parameter into the structure given by `bestFeatCombo.SVM`, `bestFeatCombo.feat`, bestFeatCombo.C` respectively.

```
        if (bestCScore < bestFeatScore) || ...
                ((bestCScore == bestFeatScore) && ...
                (length(featCombo) < length(bestFeatCombo.feat)))
            bestFeatScore = bestCScore;
            bestFeatCombo.SVM = bestCSVM;
            bestFeatCombo.feat = featCombo;
            bestFeatCombo.C = bestC;
        end
    end
```

However, note that in the `if` statement above, I am making a special case in the `or` clause. I am saying that if the current SVM performs (scores) the same as the *best so far*, but the current SVM has a smaller set of features that give the same performance, I choose to replace the *best so far* with an SVM that uses less features.

Now, at the end of the *intermediate* loop, we should have the best SVM for any set of features, with the best hyper-parameter `C` (to the extent that the grid search allows). Thus, we can compare the *current best* (stored in the structure `bestFeatCombo`) against the *overall best so far* (stored in the structure `bestSVM`).

```
    if bestFeatScore < bestSVM.Score
        bestSVM.SVMModel = bestFeatCombo.SVM;
        bestSVM.C = bestFeatCombo.C;
        bestSVM.FeaturesIdx = bestFeatCombo.feat;
        bestSVM.Score = bestFeatScore
    end    
end
```

That is the end of it. As I said, the output you want is in `bestSVM`, which contains the best SVM out of `kFolds`, for the best combination of features, and for the best hyper-parameter `C` as the grid search allows.

I hope this makes sense. Below is a working example using matlab's `fisheriris` dataset which has `100` samples and `4` features.

**Working Code:**

```
load fisheriris
inds = ~strcmp(species,'setosa');
allData = meas(inds,:);
targets = species(inds);
featSize = size(allData, 2);
kFolds = 5;     % this is where you specify your number of folds
bestSVM = struct('SVMModel', NaN, ...     % this is to store the best SVM
    'C', NaN, 'FeaturesIdx', NaN, 'Score', Inf);     

kIdx = crossvalind('Kfold', length(targets), kFolds);
for k = 1:kFolds
    trainData = allData(kIdx~=k, :);
    trainTarg = targets(kIdx~=k);
    testData = allData(kIdx==k, :);
    testTarg = targets(kIdx==k);

    % forward feature selection starts
    bestFeatScore = inf;
    bestFeatCombo = struct('SVM', NaN, 'feat', NaN, 'C', NaN);
    for b = 1:(2^featSize) - 1
        % this is to choose the features. e.g. [1 0 0] selects the first
        % feature out of three features.
        featCombo = find(de2bi(b, featSize));

        % this is the grid search for the BoxConstraint
        bestCScore = inf;
        bestC = NaN;
        bestCSVM = NaN;
        gridC = 2.^(-5:2:15);
        for C = gridC
            anSVMModel = fitcsvm(trainData(:, featCombo), trainTarg, ...
                'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
                'BoxConstraint', C);
            L = loss(anSVMModel,testData(:, featCombo), testTarg);
            if L < bestCScore        % saving best SVM on parameter
                bestCScore = L;      % selection
                bestC = C;
                bestCSVM = anSVMModel;
            end
        end

        % saving the best SVM on feature selection
        if (bestCScore < bestFeatScore) || ...
                ((bestCScore == bestFeatScore) && ...
                (length(featCombo) < length(bestFeatCombo.feat)))
            bestFeatScore = bestCScore;
            bestFeatCombo.SVM = bestCSVM;
            bestFeatCombo.feat = featCombo;
            bestFeatCombo.C = bestC;
        end
    end

    % saving the best SVM over all folds
    if bestFeatScore < bestSVM.Score
        bestSVM.SVMModel = bestFeatCombo.SVM;
        bestSVM.C = bestFeatCombo.C;
        bestSVM.FeaturesIdx = bestFeatCombo.feat;
        bestSVM.Score = bestFeatScore
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

To also answer your edited question, in which you want to have another 5-fold cross-validation for parameter selection, here is what you need to do.

Please change the *inner most* loop to look like the following:

```
        % this is the grid search for the BoxConstraint
        bestCScore = inf;
        bestC = NaN;
        gridC = 2.^(-5:2:15);
        for C = gridC
            % cross validation for parameter C
            kIdxC = crossvalind('Kfold', length(trainTarg), kFolds);
            L = zeros(1, kFolds);
            for kC = 1:kFolds
                trainDataC = trainData(kIdxC~=kC, :);
                trainTargC = trainTarg(kIdxC~=kC);
                testDataC = trainData(kIdxC==kC, :);
                testTargC = trainTarg(kIdxC==kC);
                anSVMModel = fitcsvm(trainDataC(:, featCombo), trainTargC, ...
                    'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
                    'BoxConstraint', C);
                L(kC) = loss(anSVMModel,testDataC(:, featCombo), testTargC);
            end
            L = mean(L);
            if L < bestCScore
                bestCScore = L;
                bestC = C;
            end
        end
        % we need to retrain here and save the SVM for the best C
        bestCSVM = fitcsvm(trainData(:, featCombo), trainTarg, ...
            'KernelFunction', 'RBF', 'KernelScale', 'auto', ...
            'BoxConstraint', bestC);
        bestCScore = loss(bestCSVM,testData(:, featCombo), testTarg);
```

The code uses standard CV. But note that the following line is important:

```
L(kC) = loss(anSVMModel,testDataC(:, featCombo), testTargC);
```

In this line you save all performances across all folds. However, note that you will have to average that, which is the purpose of CV.

```
L = mean(L);
```

You will also have to do some retraining, once.

Comment: Thank you Pablo! I am running it now - waiting to see the results :)

Comment: @tkoz_dk I edited my answer in response to your edited question. Since it is adding another loop, it will be more costly. Let me know if you have questions.